# Como animar botão antes dele ser clicado

Tags: java, android, animação

Aqui está uma animação que estou usando em meu projeto, só que ele recebe animação assim que é clicado:

```
Button refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        arg0.startAnimation(rotate);

        webView.loadUrl(urlOriginal);
    }
});
```

Eu gostaria de colocar a animação, assim que ele aparecer na tela, ou seja, sem precisar ser clicado para a animação iniciar.

Comment: Após obter a referência ao botão com `Button refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh);` é possível iniciar a animação com `refresh.startAnimation(rotate);`

Comment: @ramaral Tão simples quanto rir e assobiar ao mesmo tempo, haha! Exatamente isso, muito obrigado amigo!